# Python | completing multiple assignments in one line?

Tags: python

How can I complete multiple assignments in one line of code instead of having to write 10 lines of code to execute 3 commands. I am trying to build a project that uses as little lines as possible.

- I tried doing the (..., + ...) but it doesn't work.

Comment: Your goal is silly.  White space does not cost anything, and cramming multiple expressions  onto one line makes the code harder to read and therefore harder to maintain.  Remember that code is READ far more often than it is WRITTEN.

Comment: Having said that, what you want is the semicolon.  `i = 3; j = 8; k = 9`.  But if you write that while in my employ, I'll fire you.

Comment: The motivation is worrying but there are defendable reasons to want to do this. One is swapping values. You can do `a, b = b, a` in Python and swap values without needing to create a new variable. This is an example of multiple assignments on one line. It also shows why semicolon might not be how you want to go about it.

Answer (score 3):

Multiple assignments in one line:

```
x,y,z = "How","are","you"
```